# How to upload and download files with the new Google drive REST API?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I'm working on an android project where by I need to integrate Google drive api. What I realised was that the Google drive api for android is depricated including examples I found and on their site they recommend the rest api but I've been unable to make sense of the examples they have on their site regarding the new rest api. I have searched everywhere for examples but no luck. I'll be grateful if someone helps me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the Drive API REST client can be used instead:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0"
}
```

see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/).